# Gitlab CI/CD Runner error: " unrecognized import path" GOLANG

Tags: docker, go, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to implement CI/CD for a GO project

This is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: golang:latest

variables:
  REPO_NAME: gitlab.com/thomasaudo/website

before_script:
  - cd $GOPATH/src
  - mkdir -p gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE
  - cd gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE
  - ln -s $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - cd $CI_PROJECT_NAME

stages:
  - test

format:
  stage: test
  script:
    - go get ./...
    - go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go vet $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go test -race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
```

However, my runner stopped with the following error: `package website/src/routes: unrecognized import path "website/src/routes" (import path does not begin with hostname)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Aside: [`./...` doesn't match vendored packages since 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot). `go list | grep` isn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should use full paths in your import statements, e.g

```
website/src/routes
```

should become

```
gitlab.com/thomasaudo/website/src/routes
```

Also, it looks like you use `govendor`, so you are probably missing `govendor sync` command in one of your build steps.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help but it didn't fix